# Concat from a previous column

Tags: mysql

Is there a way for me to concat a column from a previous column determined by logic?

```
    
    select
    if(p.mfg is not null , p.mfg, 'Private') as MFG,
    concat(MFG, " ",p.sku) as TITLE
    from product p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement like

```
select
if(p.mfg is not null , p.mfg, 'Private') as MFG,
concat(case when p.mfg is not null then p.mfg else 'Private' end, " ",p.sku) as TITLE
from product p
```

(OR) using an `inline view` like

```
select MFG, concat(MFG, " ", sku) as TITLE
from (select if(p.mfg is not null , p.mfg, 'Private') as MFG, sku from product p
    ) tab
```